# SQLite Database Population from External Site

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I'm a beginner in both the android app development space and SQLite, however I want to write an app where you type in the name of a wine and it will give you a reccomendation of foods along with their ratings of how good the food-wine pairing was.

I've been looking at SQLite and SugarORM which supposedly makes SQLite a lot easier to use. Next I wanted to pull the database information from http://www.whattopair.com/ which has the entire database I want for my app.

Is it possible to pre-populate the database with the database from that website without having to manually enter thousands of these pairings? Perhaps I have to contact the site owner?

Thanks, and I apologize if anything is unclear, but I'm a complete novice using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with the site if they provide an API to fetch information from their database pragmatically.
If they do, you can write a program that will run the first time your app starts, that will fetch the information and store it locally on the device.
You should check how much disk space that will take because the phone's memory is much more limited than the website's database.
It might be best to connect to the websites database on-demand and only fetch the info you need.

Android developers training can get you started, and they cover the topics of fetching information from web services, and writing to the local database.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't get too offended by my answer, but it's the answer you need to hear. =)

The whole point of the website you linked is to provide people with the wine and food pairing. They make money by having people come to their site via ads.

They aren't going to want to let you use their data for free so you can also make money. =(

You can obviously scrape the data or manually enter it in, but that is really the same as stealing. Plus it would be hard to keep up with them as they add more/new data.

I doubt they have an API based on the look of the site.

It's better to just start from scratch and create your *own* database of food and wine pairings. Then you won't run into issues of being sued etc.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will request permission from the site owner and if they don't get back to me, I will start my own database